# C++ - Copy constructor with pointers as the data field

Tags: c++, pointers, class-constructors

I have the following code :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A { 
    int *val;
public:
    A() { val = new int; *val = 0; }
    int get() { return ++(*val); } 
};

int main() {
    A a,b = a;

    A c,d = c;

    cout << a.get() << b.get() ;
    cout << endl ; 

    cout << c.get() << endl ;//
    cout << d.get() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the output as :-

```
21
1
2
```

The behavior in case of c.get and d.get is easy to understand. 
Both c and d share the same pointer val and a and b share the same pointer val.

So c.get() should return 1 and d.get() should return 2.
But I was expecting similar behavior in a.get() and b.get(). (maybe I have not understood cout properly)

I am unable to understand how a.get() is producing 2.

Can you explain why I am getting such an output. According to me the output should have been :-

```
12
1
2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cout << a.get() << b.get() ;
```

gets executed as:

```
cout.operator<<(a.get()).operator<<(b.get());
```

In this expression, whether `a.get()` gets called first or `b.get()` gets called first is not specified by the language. It is platform dependent.

You can separate them into two statements to make sure they get executed in an expected order.

```
cout << a.get();
cout << b.get();
```

Comment: So I can use a paranthesis maybe to make it consistent with the c and d case ?

Comment: @illogical, I can't think of how one can use parenthesis to force an order but you can certainly separate them into two statements.

Comment: @illogical, Precedence doesn't specify the unspecified evaluation order. Since `operator<<` is left-associative, it's already as if you had written it like `(cout << a.get()) << b.get();` The `get` calls can happen whenever as long as the left `operator<<` is called with the `a` result before the right one is called with the `b` result.